# How to filter vertical html table with javascript

Tags: javascript

found many javascript scripts to filter html tables but they all seem to only work with horizontal tables. need to be able to filter whole records of vertical layout html table. any pointers?

Alternatively, is there a way to write a html vertical table without repeating field headers and thus make the structure more repeated record like? That should make it more amenable to filtering

Comment: Make yourself familiar with the [DOM API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model).

Comment: i know DOM, trying to find a html filter javascript that can do the job without reinventing wheel, hopefully there's a script that is not hardcoded throughout to work on horizontal tables only

Comment: Asking for external resources (e.g. scripts) is off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically this is off-topic, as you're not supposed to ask for reviews or suggestions of external libraries - as it's bound to open more discussion than just a simple answer. "Product or service recommendations or comparisons" is listed under "Don't ask about" on the Tour page (https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Seeing, however, as I've just written some code that could help you with this 'issue', I will post it here for you. Please remember for next time that SO is for assistance with scripts - where you've posted a minimal copy of your code so that the issue can be replicated by us. You should specify the issue you're having and what you've tried so far.

In any case; here's a small vertical table with some filters:

```
<div>
  First Name:<input class='filter' row='1'>
  Last Name:<input class='filter' row='2'>
</div>
<table border='1'>
  <tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <td>Bill</td>
    <td>Mark</td>
    <td>Steve</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <td>Gates</td>
    <td>Zuckerberg</td>
    <td>Wozniak</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here's a script to make it filter-able:

```
var filterTable = $('table');
$('.filter').keyup(function(){
  var hide = [];
  $('.filter').each(function(){
    var val = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    var row = $(this).attr('row');
    $('table tr:nth-child(' + row + ') td').each(function(){
      if($.inArray($(this).index(), hide) == -1 && $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(val) == -1)
        hide.push($(this).index());
    });
  });
  filterTable.find('tr td').each(function(){
    if($.inArray($(this).index(), hide) != -1)
      $(this).hide();
    else
      $(this).show();
  });
});
```

And here's a link to a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aacden58/

Comment: thanks very much. will ponder this. i note you're not repeating your <th> tags, which i do for every record. i'll take a look at my xslt, which is where i generate the table, originally from an excel spreadsheet.

Comment: thanks to this question/conversation i was able to work out that the problem is actually with presenting html tables in vertical layout. i've created a new question to ask about that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37289378/vertical-html-table-without-repeating-th-tags