# Vertical html table without repeating th tags

Tags: html, html-table

I'm generating a table using xslt, but for this question I'll keep that side out of it, as it relates more to the actual generated structure of a html table.
What I do is make a vertical table as follows, which suits the layout needed for the data concerned that originated in a spreadsheet. Example is contrived for brevity, actual data fields contain lengthy strings and many more fields.

```
Title: something or rather bla bla
Description: very long desription
Field1: asdfasdfasdfsdfsd
Field2: asdfasfasdfasdfsdfjasdlfksdjaflk

Title: another title
Description: another description
Field1:
Field2: my previous field was blank but this one is not, anyways
```

etc.
The only way so far I found to generate such a html table is using repeating  tags for every field and every record e.g.:

```html
<tr><th>Title</th><td>something or rather bla bla</td></tr>
<tr><th>Description</th><td>very long desription</td></tr>
...
<tr><th>Title</th><td>another title</td></tr>
<tr><th>Description</th><td>another description</td></tr>
...
```

Of course this is semantically incorrect but produces correct visual layout. I need it to be semantically correct html, as that's the only sane way of later attaching a filtering javascript facility.
The following correct semantically produces an extremely wide table with a single set of field headers on the left:

```html
<tr><th>Title</th><td>something or rather bla bla</td><td>another title</td></tr>
<tr><th>Description</th><td>very long desription</td><td>another description</td></tr>
...
```

So to summarise, need a html table (or other html structure) where it's one record under another (visually) with repeating field headers, but the field headers must not be repeated in actual code because that would wreck any record based filtering to be added later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo. Thanks for updating your question, and including some code. Typically you'd also post what you've tried to correct this issue - but I'm satisfied enough with this post.

Since you want the repeating headers in vertical layout (not something I've seen often, but I can understand the desire), you don't *have* to modify the HTML formatting, just use a bit more JavaScript to figure it out. I haven't gone through and checked to see if I'm doing things efficiently (I'm probably not, since there are so many loops), but in my testing the following can attach to a vertical table and filter using a couple variables to indicate how many rows there are in each entry.

Firstly, here's the HTML I'm testing this one with. Notice I have a `div` with the `id` of `filters`, and each of my filter inputs has a custom attribute named `filter` that matches the header of the rows they are supposed to filter:

```
<div id='filters'>
  Title: <input filter='Title'><br>
  Desc: <input filter='Description'>
</div>
<table>
  <tr><th>Title</th><td>abcd</td></tr>
  <tr><th>Description</th><td>efgh</td></tr>
  <tr><th>Title</th><td>ijkl</td></tr>
  <tr><th>Description</th><td>mnop</td></tr>
  <tr><th>Title</th><td>ijkl</td></tr>
  <tr><th>Description</th><td>mdep</td></tr>
  <tr><th>Title</th><td>ijkl</td></tr>
  <tr><th>Description</th><td>mnop</td></tr>
  <tr><th>Title</th><td>ijkl</td></tr>
  <tr><th>Description</th><td>mnop</td></tr>
</table>
```

Here are the variables I use at the start:

```
var filterTable = $('table');
var rowsPerEntry = 2;
var totalEntries = filterTable.find('tbody tr').size() / rowsPerEntry;
var currentEntryNumber = 1;
var currentRowInEntry = 0;
```

And this little loop will add a class for each entry (based on the rowsPerEntry as seen above) to group the rows together (this way all rows for an entry can be selected together with a class selector in jQuery):

```
filterTable.find('tbody tr').each(function(){
  $(this).addClass('entry' + currentEntryNumber);
  currentRowInEntry += 1;
  if(currentRowInEntry == rowsPerEntry){
    currentRowInEntry = 0;
    currentEntryNumber += 1;
  }
});
```

And the magic; on keyup for the filters run a loop through the total number of entries, then a nested loop through the filters to determine if that entry does not match either filter's input. If either field for the entry does not match the corresponding filter value, then we add the entry number to our `hide` array and move along. Once we've determined which entries should be hidden, we can show all of the entries, and hide the specific ones that should be hidden:

```
$('#filters input').keyup(function(){
  var hide = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < totalEntries; i++){
    var entryNumber = i + 1;
    if($.inArray(entryNumber, hide) == -1){
      $('#filters input').each(function(){
        var val = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        var fHeader = $(this).attr('filter');
        var fRow = $('.entry' + entryNumber + ' th:contains(' + fHeader + ')').closest('tr');
        if(fRow.find('td').text().toLowerCase().indexOf(val) == -1){
          hide.push(entryNumber);
          return false;
        }
      });
    }
  }
  filterTable.find('tbody tr').show();
  $.each(hide, function(k, v){
    filterTable.find('.entry' + v).hide();
  });
});
```

It's no masterpiece, but I hope it'll get you started down the right path.

Here's a fiddle too: https://jsfiddle.net/bzjyfejc/

Comment: i've made the xslt spit out consistent full set of fields, eventhough some records have missing data. it's only about 300 records, but the information is somewhat valuable in being able to traverse it nicely. i'm on a mission to replace current thing which is a hidden excel sheet and a front sheet with ugly VB search form. thanks a lot for the code, i shall steal the ideas from it.

Comment: fyi I'll be adding also a 'Any' filter, that will filter on all fields. also adding drop-down filters for some fields that have enumerated values.